# Obtain high resolution data for Papua New Guinea-Madang Province (QGIS)

Tags: geospatial, climate

I'm currently working with a dataset of contagious bird illness in Papua New Guinea (specific for the Madang Province) and I would like to plot it in a map and try to run a few models, however all the climatic and geographical data that I've managed to found is usually for larger scales.

Has anyone on the forum worked with Papua New Guinea in the past and knows where to find high resolution climatic layers of mean temperature/rain. Also landcover, NDVI and land-use layers?

Also, does anyone know where to find very precise river layers, including not only the main rivers, but tiny streams, ponds, etc?